# Reactjs client needs to force refresh after deploy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, production-environment

Every time that a new deploy is made to production or any other environment the client needs to force a refresh and clear cache with ctrl shift r to updated the UI, the project was made with Create-React-App.

Already added the meta tags to HTML file but didn't work

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

Is there any kind of config I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried to wait around 10 minutes?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski yes, sometimes it takes more than 1 day

Answer (score 2):

Your src/index.js file should look like this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.register();
```

Just change the

```
serviceWorker.register();
```

For

```
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score 0):

add meta tags inside the head tag to make sure that the content of the page isn’t cached.

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, maybe you need cache control

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

OR read this one https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/

Answer (score 0):

Which version of CRA are you using? If it's caused due to ServiceWorker then you should disable the ServiceWorker.

`import { unregister } from './registerServiceWorker';`

`unregister();`

Comment: Im using react-scripts 4.0.3, how can I know that it is from ServiceWorker?